# Why are Google's API response objects' property keys random two-character strings?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus

So I just started using Google's Gplus API for an app I'm developing and everything's working fine, but I am really confused by the fact that Google's response object seems to have totally random two-character strings for its property keys. For example, here's what I'm getting:

```
WE {El: "100327378902537923764", Ka: Object, wc: PG}
El: "100327378902537923764" 
Ka: Object
wc: PG
Ka: "100327378902537923764"
Ld: "Thomas Moore"
wc: "example@gmail.com"
zt: "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-example/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAMPA/Vo75ASRTN_k/s96-c/photo.jpg"
```

I'm using the JavaScript sdk and Angular. Very curious if anyone has a reasonable explanation for this

EDIT: Here's the request I'm making:

```
 gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().then(function (googleAuth) {
            googleAuth.signIn({ 'scope': 'profile email' }).then(function (result) {}
```

Comment: What specific request are you making?

Comment: It looks like you are using a private API and not one of the [documented public APIs](https://developers.google.com/+/).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by private API... googleAuth.signIn() is a documented function. Could you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google exposes these properties via convenient getter methods. For instance, to get profile information, you can use the following getters of `gapi.oauth2.BasicProfile` object:

```
// profile id
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile().getId();
// profile name
gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().currentUser.get().getBasicProfile().getName();
```

Comment: "convenient" well, that's certainly an opinion

Comment: I'm noticing that the getters don't actually always work either. Painful.